# Script doesn't want to run from python shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line

I open C:\Python27\python.exe, I type clean_index.py (which is a file located in C:\Python27) and I get:

```
>>> clean_index.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'clean_index' is not defined
```

What's this all about?
I type C:\Python27\clean_index.py, same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [execfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile):

```
>>>execfile('clean_index.py')
```

or just run it directly (not within the python shell):

```
$ python clean_index.py
```

assuming you have `python` in your path.

Or, use an `import` in the python shell:

```
>>>import fibo
>>>fibo.fib(1000)
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987
```

Module import sample taken from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html). The filename is `fibo.py`.

Since you probably simply want to run the file, I suggest you use the **second** option.

Comment: I think it is important to clarify that when you say "run it directly" you mean from your normal terminal shell (bash, command prompt, etc.), not the interactive python shell.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes I was indicating that you're in the python prompt with `>>>` but that's a good point, it's kind of unclear

Comment: Yes, `>>>` is clear that it's the Python prompt, but for the other prompts you could use `$`, `#`, `>`...  There's too many to choose from!  I just thought that since the OP thought you could use the Python prompt as a general command line prompt, they would probably be unclear about what to do without explicitly saying to run `python clean_index.py` in the normal shell.